# How to debug when using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using [Google Analytics debugger tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) for Chrome.

Actually what I want is to see if request are being made and then see my custom variables in Google Analytics, I am coding blindly.

I am trying this in localhost:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'city', 'delhi', 3]);
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[1,city,delhi,3]":  ga_debug.js:18
0

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
Tracking beacon sent!
```

I also tried with this before setting and sending variable:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[none]":  ga_debug.js:18
0
```

But in the moment I don't see any custom variable in my account page, do they take time to appear?, how long?

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing an an array to `_gaq.push` -- you're missing the `[]`s in your example

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'city', 'delhi', 3]);
```